# How do I select namespace into which generated C# classes are put?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-diagram

I'm generating a platoon of C# classes from an UML Class Diagram in Visual Studio 2013 (Update 5). When generated, a new "SchematicsLib" project appears in my solution, and the generated code is then placed into the "GeneratedCode" folder of this new project, no namespaces.

```
MyProject
|-- App_Code
|   |-- Entities
|   `-- ...
`-- ...

SchematicsLib
`-- GeneratedCode
    |-- GeneratedClassA.cs
    `-- ...

MyProjectDiagrams
`-- classes.classdiagram
```

I'd wish to place the generated code into a folder (reflecting namespace structure) in an existing project of mine, to MyProject/App_Code/Entities - the classes should also be wrapped in the namespace `MyProject.App_Code.Entities` as well. How may I accomplish this if I'd wish to keep code generation to a single step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define a namespace on your UML. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465144(v=vs.120).aspx.) are directions on how to do this. Another [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx) in that article states:

> If the UML type is contained in a package, the generated C# type is placed inside a namespace, and the file is generated in a folder that has the same name as the namespace.

Comment: You beat me to it by 1 minute. That's exactly what I figured just now, packages are a convenient and straightforward tool.